# Laravel - PHP function search string from multidimensional array in 8 ways

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for a function that searchs a word, like "ONE" in a multidimentional array, but I need to find the word in all the 8 ways, example "from left to right, from right to left, up to down, down to up and diagonal upper to diagonal lower"

The array's size may vary (3x3, 1x10, 5x5, 7x2).

I already tried to make this in nested if's, but I don't like that way.

I need to count how many times the word appears in my array, I dont know if exist a php or laravel function that resolve this problem or I must create one

Comment: Have you tried recursion.....  I don't really see how direction matters,  Personally I would use `preg_grep` and a sprinkle of recursion. but that's just me...

Answer (score 0):

I translate [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-a-word-in-a-2d-grid-of-characters/) C++ code into PHP. It works fine and returns the same result as C++ code.

```
/**
 * This function searches in all 8-direction from point
 * @param array $grid
 * @param int $row in grid[][]
 * @param int $col in grid[][]
 * @param string $word
 * @return bool
 */
function search2D(array $grid, int $row, int $col, string $word): bool {
    $x = [-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
    $y = [-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1];

    // Rows and columns in given grid
    $R = count($grid);
    $C = count($grid[0]);

    // If first character of word doesn't match with
    // given starting point in grid.
    if ($grid[$row][$col]!= $word[0])
        return false;

    $len = strlen($word);

    for ($dir = 0; $dir < 8; $dir++)
    {
        // Initialize starting point for current direction
        $rd = $row + $x[$dir];
        $cd = $col + $y[$dir];

        // First character is already checked, match remaining
        // characters
        for ($k = 1; $k < $len; $k++)
        {
            // If out of bound break
            if ($rd >= $R || $rd < 0 || $cd >= $C || $cd < 0)
                break;

            // If not matched,  break
            if ($grid[$rd][$cd] != $word[$k])
                break;

            //  Moving in particular direction
            $rd += $x[$dir];
            $cd += $y[$dir];
        }

        // If all character matched, then value of must
        // be equal to length of word
        if ($k == $len)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Searches given word in a given matrix in all 8 directions
 * @param array $grid
 * @param string $word
 */
function patternSearch(array $grid, string $word):void {
    // Rows and columns in given grid
    $R = count($grid);
    $C = count($grid[0]);

    // Consider every point as starting point and search
    // given word
    for ($row = 0; $row < $R; $row++)
       for ($col = 0; $col < $C; $col++)
          if (search2D($grid, $row, $col, $word))
              echo "pattern found at {$row}, {$col}" . "\r\n";
}

$grid = [
    ['G','E','E','K','S','F','O','R','G','E','E','K','S'],
    ['G','E','E','K','S','Q','U','I','Z','G','E','E','K'],
    ['I','D','E','Q','A','P','R','A','C','T','I','C','E'],
];

patternSearch($grid, 'GEEKS');
echo "\r\n";
patternSearch($grid, 'EEE');
```

**Output:**

```
pattern found at 0, 0
pattern found at 0, 8
pattern found at 1, 0

pattern found at 0, 2
pattern found at 0, 10
pattern found at 2, 2
pattern found at 2, 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function searchWord($array, $word) {
    $rows = count($array);
    $cols = count($array[0]);
    $directions = [
        [-1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1],
        [0, -1], [0, 1],
        [1, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1]
    ];
    $count = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
            foreach ($directions as $dir) {
                $k = 0;
                $x = $i;
                $y = $j;
                while (isset($array[$x][$y]) && $array[$x][$y] === $word[$k]) {
                    $x += $dir[0];
                    $y += $dir[1];
                    $k++;
                    if ($k === strlen($word)) {
                        $count++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $count;
}
```

The function takes in two parameters: `$array` which is the multi-dimensional `array` and `$word` which is the word to be searched.

The function first initializes the `$directions` `array` which contains 8 possible directions to search the word.

Then, it loops through the array and checks each character in the array. For each character, it loops through all 8 directions to see if the word can be found by following that direction. If the word is found, the count is incremented. The loop continues until all directions for all characters have been checked.

Finally, the function returns the count of the number of times the word appears in the array.

Comment: I'd advise to use human-readable names for variables this makes it a lot easier to read. For example, use $rowIndex instead of $i or $colIndex etc. I'd probably also split the code into multiple parts. Otherwise, it looks like you put in quite some effort for this answer. Good. Keep it up. :)